# How to make fixed mask when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the elements mask like this image when scrolling, but I tried adjusting the CSS -webkit-mask property, but it didn't work as I wanted.

[image]

Top: when on the top, Bottom: when scrolling

If you find it difficult to implement this with CSS alone, is there another way to implement it using JS or jQuery?

Comment: Please share your `code` and what you tried so far.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: [The website shown in the image](https://tbh.kr/album/joukei-dorobou) I tried various `-webkit-mask-*` on `body>#bg>main.album` but it failed.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 1):

adds a extra layer for the mask, nail the mask top left and let the context scroll under the mask. Based on this, the mask is now shifted. You need a spacer for the content that he is not hidden by the mask. Just as a idea.

```
  .mask{
    position:fixed;
    top : 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index:1000;
  }
  .content{
    position:relative;
    left:200px; /*mask width */
  }
```